# Print Map object into array

Tags: javascript

I have a map object which looks like this

```
[[3,1],[34,1],[1,2],[2,2]]
```

The key is the element and the value is the frequency it should appear in the array. How do I achieve it to look like the below array?

```
[3,34,1,1,2,2]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` as follows:

```js
const generateArr = (elementFrequencyPairs=[]) => 
  elementFrequencyPairs.reduce((acc, [element, frequency]) => {
    const current = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < frequency; i++) current.push(element);
    return [...acc, ...current];
  }, []);
  
console.log( ...generateArr([[3,1],[34,1],[1,2],[2,2]]) );
```